# Find the point with minimum max distance to any point in a set

Tags: computational-geometry

Say I have a set of points on a 2d plane, how do I find the point(s) where the maximum euclidian distance to any of the points in the set is minimized?

Answer (score 7):

This is the [smallest enclosing circle problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smallest-circle_problem), and can be solved in linear time. Also, [these slides](http://www.cs.uu.nl/docs/vakken/ga/slides4b.pdf) describe a randomized algorithm that runs in expected linear time.